# Not able to Read Symbol from word file using c#

Tags: c#, interop

[image: Word document]

I am not able to get µ(alt+230, U+00B5) symbol from word using Interop in c#.

when i am trying to get text like `document.characters[1].text` this shows "(" in place of µ symbol.
Attempted to perform this action:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= Document.Characters.Count; i++) 
{ 
  var chr = Document.Characters[i]; 
  var ascii = (int) chr.Text[0]; 
  Console.WriteLine(chr.Text);
}
```

Please help if anyone know.

Thanks

Comment: Every character is reading perfectly but not symbol

Comment: and where do you *show* that character?

Comment: actually i am trying to store in database for use on web.I converted image and Math type to LATEX but symbol is creating problem.

Comment: Here is word file link [ https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mouerfi47s1ufp/character.docx?dl=0 ]

Comment: It would be better if you post the sequence of chars. And how you are creating the document object

Comment: I tried to read character by character too but no use : '            for (var i = 1; i <= Document.Characters.Count; i++)
            {
                
                var chr = Document.Characters[i];
                var ascii = (int) chr.Text[0]; Console.WriteLine(chr.Text);}' but still all symbol is giving "(" charcter

Comment: I am using document in following way  `            var application = new word.Application();
            Application = application;
            application.Visible = fileVisible;
            var document = application.Documents.Open(FileName);`

Comment: Well, it's not a character, it's a symbol…

Comment: @stuartd yes its symbol but if you see last symbol of first line I mean infinite its coming through Interop but theta and mu is not coming

Comment: In the document you uploaded to dropbox, doubling clicking on the μ and θ characters opens the symbol dialog - but it does not open for the ∞, which suggests it's just a regular character

Comment: @stuartd yes i read those as character because when i am looping through each character there is no way to check that particular character is symbol or character.

Comment: code works only in the case where the symbols have been added to WORD by changing the font to 'SYMBOL', but not when the symbol has been added to the document via the Symbol UI (which, unfortunately is how it was done in the documents I need to process)

Comment: Document.Open() has a crap ton of available parameters. did you try passing in an Encoding param? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx

Comment: @pijemcolu what encoding i should mention can you please show example code It will be great help thanks

Comment: Utf8 supports miu so maybe that would work? 65001 is the encoding enum value for utf8 -> Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref  missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 65001, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

Comment: @pijemcolu I did following change in code ` var document = application.Documents.Open(FileName,Encoding:MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8); ` but still no change

Comment: I cant even see the symbols when I open the document you uploaded..

Comment: @Jbjstam please open the file with latest word application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know and have been able to research it is not possible to get the actual value from a character that is inserted by means of the Insert Symbol dialog as is explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bed16cf1-0c39-4fce-85c2-c48632aab095/symbols-and-fields).

As I doubt the interop route will give you that character I implemented the XML route (better would probably be to use OpenXML at this stage but I simply used the interop I already had).

This code example gives you the text from the document for the nodes I processed, in this case the  `<w:t>` and `w:sym` nodes.

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

var doc = app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"C:\Users\rschrieken\Downloads\character-safe.docx", Encoding: MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUSASCII);

// forget Interop, hello XML
var cd = XDocument.Parse(doc.WordOpenXML);

var w = (XNamespace)"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var para in cd.Descendants(w + "p"))
{
    foreach (var node in para.Descendants())
    {
        if (node.Name.LocalName == "t")
        {
            Console.Write(node.Value);
            sb.Append(node.Value);
        }
        if (node.Name.LocalName == "sym")
        {
            var sym = node.Attribute(w + "char").Value;
            // this will convert the hex value
            var val = Convert.ToInt32(sym, 16);
            // depending on your requirements, you might have to re-map this
            // but I simply assume here that hex value is an valid Unicode char 
            Console.Write((char)val);
            sb.Append((char) val);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    sb.AppendLine();
}
// sb.ToString() gives you the text from the document
```

[image]

You will not see the mu character here because the font used by the Console doesn't have a glyph defined for that char value.

Comment: Its great ... Actually i am using Interop so that i can get math equation and convert to LATEX on fly using SDK [link](https://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/) given by MathType .. so in that i use to select inlineshape and copy to clipboard and then using their function get string of LATEX which save in database.I tried a lot with openxml but could not do. I will try once again with the help of your code.... Again Thanks a lot

Comment: I am unable to show on html page [According to your code i am able to get ascii code but when i am trying to use on web page as &#ASCIIcode; its just shows some wiered things

Comment: That means that the font used on the webpage doesn't have a glyph for that character. Use a `<span class='symbol'>&#d084;<span>` and then define  in your css `.symbol { font: <font that has the glyph>; }`

Comment: I too think same way so i am adding manually As Code given below:

Comment: if (node.Name.LocalName == "sym")
                    {
                        var xAttribute = node.Attribute(w + "char");
                        if (xAttribute != null)
                        {
                            var sym = xAttribute.Value;

                            // this will convert the hex value
                            var val = Convert.ToInt32(sym, 16);

                            // depending on your requirements, you might have to re-map this
            sb.Append(new Symbol().GetSymbol(val));
                        }
                    }

Comment: `public class Symbol
    {
        private Dictionary<int,string> SymDictionary=new Dictionary<int, string>();
        public Symbol()
        {
  SymDictionary.Add(61532, "&#8756;");
        }
        public string GetSymbol(int ascii)
        {
            if (SymDictionary.ContainsKey(ascii))
                return SymDictionary[ascii];
            else
            return $"[#SYM{ascii}SYM#]";
        }
    }`

Comment: Its Worked!!!!! `$"<font face='Symbol'>&#{val};</font>";` where val is ASCII code.... Thanks @rene